# QtNetworkAccessManaget issue getting Japanese character containing web page source.

Tags: qt

In my Qt QUI application I need to get WebPage source using QNetworkAccessManager.
My problem is while I am trying to get Page Source of those belongs Japan Country and containing Japanese words so that Japanese words are coming in some undefined format.

How can I get that page source as it is with Japanese chartacters and save it into QString object.

Example Page Url is :http://www.amazon.co.jp/BUFFALO-外付けハードディスク-Regza-HD-LB2-0TU2-フラストレーションフリーパッケージ/dp/B0052VIGXA/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1366439116&sr=1-1

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'undefined' format and how you analyse a content of QString you have. QNetworkAccessManager gets raw data received from http, so then you do something like.

```
QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
```

you should analysed received header for encoding and make appropriate conversion.

Comment: Yes I am receiving reply using same                                                              QByteArray data = reply->readAll(); 

And also analysed received header that is                      {Content-Type: text/html; charset=Shift_JIS}.                                     But I am not getting how to make conversion?

Undefined Format Means like following:

" BUFFALO �O�t���n�[�h�f�B�X�N PC/�Ɠd�Ή� egza[���O�U]/Aquos[�A�N�I�X]) 2TB HD-LB2.0TU2/N [�t���X�g���[�V�����t���[�p�b�P�[�W(FFP)] "

Comment: check QTextCodec documentation